# What algorithm to use to find the non-linear mapping function between 2D shapes generated from biosignals attractors?

Tags: conformal-geometry, neural-networks, nonlinear-analysis, mapping-class-group

I have two biosignals recording the same phenomenon with different methods.

Target signal is a reference signal and I would like to find some non-linear mapping from the original signal to the target signal.

I generated attractors from these two signals (see figures), and I would like to know what kind of algorithm you suggest to find the non-linear mapping from the original signal to the target signal.

Would Growing Neural Gas (GNG) or some type of Self-Organizing Map (SOM) algorithm work in that sense?

[Target signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAkqz.png)
[Original signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIb1a.png)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What about the second signal?

Comment: There are two links: target signal and original signal, or are you asking something else?

Comment: A neural network would suffice. Do you have numerical data to make a test?

Comment: Sure, would you need the time-series data or its projection with the attractor?

Comment: Why not! Let us try. Time series better.

Comment: [signal 1](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApJAFRgKDx50alacTjOgEy5B1d0) [signal 2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApJAFRgKDx50aZyOo8MLqH2tRX8)

Comment: Thanks for the data.

Comment: @Cesareo what neural network architecture are you using for that task? Do you have any link to a repo? I have only used PyTorch neural networks for image recognition.

Comment: I am trying to do it using keras  (python). As long as I understood, the paths described in signal1 and signal2 should be $2\times n$ arrays each but the files contain only one signal ($x$ or $y$) because one of  the two entries is the time index. It is correct?

Comment: In time, the neural network I will be using is a LSTM Recurrent Neural Network

Comment: @Cesareo that is correct: in each file the first column is the timestamp (or time index) and the second column contains the values of the signal. I'd be interested in seeing your code in Keras, once you've succeeded, if it's ok with you of course.

Comment: LTSM RNN would predict the next occurrences in a time-series, right? So, you're saying it could be used as well to find out the non-linear mapping function between the two time-series?

Comment: Yes. The nn will have one series as input an the other as output. If I succeed It will be a pleasure to let my code at your disposal. Any way I will need the complete input - output signals.

Comment: Hi @Cesareo did you manage to get the nn to work?

Comment: Hi @Bernard Delvaux As I cited previously, I need for input-output data with the structure $(t_k, x_i(t_k),y_i(t_k)), (t_k, x_o(t_k), y_o(t_k))$ and I received data with the structure $(t_k,x_i(t_k)), (t_k, x_o(t_k))$ Is it right? Regards.

Comment: @Cesareo you received indeed data with the structure $(t_k,x_i(t_k)),(t_k,x_o(t_k))$ : these are the input and output time-series respectively, I don't have anything else. So, at each timestamp $t_k$ corresponds an amplitude $x_i(t_k)$ (or $x_o(t_k)$). The mapping I am interested in, is $x_i(t_k) -> x_o(t_k)$

Comment: Well, I had understood from the figures, that the orbits were two-dimensional for input and for output for  every moment $t_k$ I will try to obtain then for those uni-dimensional data.

Comment: @Cesareo the orbits were from attractors

Comment: I published a basic script  to do the task

Comment: There is a brand new approach to solve this problem. Please see at https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.07366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic attempt to build a functional relationship between input and output data. Follows a basic python scrip which configures a LSTM with a hidden layer and 10 delays. This script can be enhanced by considering more hidden layers and more delays. This script is a mixture of cut and paste over existing code accessible via internet.

`import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import array
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense`


`datain  = pd.read_pickle('signal1.pkl')
dataout = pd.read_pickle('signal2.pkl')`


`"""
discarding the 200 first values
"""
din  = list(datain.values)[200:]
dout = list(dataout.values)[200:]`


`def media(data):
    s = 0;
    for dato in data:
        s += dato
    return s/len(data)`


`def translate(data,media):
    data_translated = []
    for dato in data:
        data_translated.append(dato-media)
    return data_translated`


`"""

univariate data preparation
"""
"""
split a univariate sequence into samples
"""
def split_sequence(sequence_in, sequence_out, n_steps):
    (X, y) = (list(), list())
    for i in range(len(sequence_in)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        # check if we are beyond the sequence
        if end_ix > len(sequence_in)-1:
            break
        # gather input and output parts of the pattern
        (seq_x, seq_y) = (sequence_in[i:end_ix], sequence_out[end_ix])
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return (array(X), array(y))`


`"""
define input sequence
"""
seq_in  = translate(din,media(din))
seq_out = translate(dout,media(dout))`


`fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.gca()
ax.plot(seq_in,seq_out)
plt.title('Raw data')
plt.show()`


`"""
choose a number of time steps
"""
n_steps = 10
"""
split into samples
"""
(X, y) = split_sequence(seq_in, seq_out, n_steps)
"""
define model
"""
n_features = 1
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))
"""
define model
"""
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
"""
fit model
"""
model.fit(X, y, epochs = 800, verbose = 0)
"""
demonstrate prediction
"""
rec = []
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    x_input = X[i]
    x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
    x_input = x_input.reshape((1, n_steps, n_features))
    yhat    = model.predict(x_input, verbose = 0)
    rec.append(yhat[0][0])`


`pd.DataFrame(seq_in).plot.line()
pd.DataFrame(seq_out).plot.line()
pd.DataFrame(rec).plot.line()`


`fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.gca()
ax.plot(seq_in[n_steps:],rec)
plt.title('Adjusted data')
plt.show()`